# Expanding shortened URLs with Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to expand a shortened URL in my Meteor app, one that may have been shortened multiple times.
I've followed the node.js example given by Axel Rauschmayer here: http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/expand-urls.html

His basic node.js example looks like:

```
var request = require("request");

function expandUrl(shortUrl) {
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            console.log(response.request.href);
        });
}
```

I've tried to re-implement it using Meteor's http package (which I believe is built upon the same 'request' node package as used above).

My attempt at doing this in Meteor with a goo.gl url that goes to a bit.ly url which goes to the meteor subreddit looks like:

```
HTTP.call("HEAD", 'http://bit.ly/1adkwWO',{},
        function (error, result){
            if (!error){
                console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("statusCode: " + result.statusCode);
                console.log("data: " + result.data);
                console.log("headers: " + JSON.stringify(result.headers));
                console.log("href: " + result.request.href);

            }else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

and results in a console log that looks like:

```
I20150410-08:43:10.961(1)? statusCode: 200
I20150410-08:43:10.961(1)? data: null
I20150410-08:43:10.961(1)? headers: {"date":"Fri, 10 Apr 2015 07:43:10 GMT","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","connection":"keep-alive","set-cookie":["__cfduid=d1c9e25e3211f8c83df44b779033c8cc81428651790; expires=Sat, 09-Apr-16 07:43:10 GMT; path=/; domain=.reddit.com; HttpOnly"],"x-ua-compatible":"IE=edge","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","vary":"accept-encoding","x-moose":"majestic","cache-control":"no-cache","cf-cache-status":"MISS","server":"cloudflare-nginx","cf-ray":"1d4cd1b8b5c81347-LHR"}
I20150410-08:43:10.974(1)? Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined
I20150410-08:43:10.974(1)?     at app/twittest.js:91:58
I20150410-08:43:10.974(1)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

I can see that I am getting back the response from reddit as the domain 'reddit.com' appears in the headers, but I am not able to retrieve the URL since the response object does not exist.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong, has the request module changed since the example I posted above?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(result.request)` ?

Comment: console.log(result.request) returns undefined